# How to wait to load a Crystal Reports File On ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, crystal-reports, pageload

I have a problem with a website I have.

There's a button that opens a Crystal Reports File. Most of the time, it loads properly, but there have been times that it does not load anything.

I noticed that if I click the button as soon as the main page loads, and the report is opened, it does not load (even if you try to refresh or reload the report). If you wait at least 3 seconds and press the button, the report loads properly (normally works when I open a report, does not load, close the window, press the button again, it loads properly).

I know it sounds like a silly problem, but any user always reports that the file doesn't open, and end up giving up using my system. I need to find out how to repair this issue, where can I start from?

Report file (cs)

```
ReportDocument oRpt = new ReportDocument();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["idInvoice"] != null)
            {
                Invoices invoice = new Invoices(int.Parse(Session["idInvoice"].ToString()));
                Client client = new Client(invoice.idClient);

                if (invoice.isRestricted || client.restrictInvoiceAccess)
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "msg", "window.alert('El acceso a este archivo fue restringido (" + Session["idInvoice"].ToString() + ").');window.close();", true);
                    return;
                }

                loadReport(invoice.idClient, invoice.idInvoice);
            }
        }

        private void loadReport(int pi_idClient, int pi_idInvoice)
        {
            bool isCFD = false;
            string originalString = "", signedString = "", approvedYear = "",
                approvedNumber = "", certificateNum = "", series = "", number = "",
                clientName = "", clientDir = "", clientRFC = "", banckReference = string.Empty, 
                payMethod = string.Empty, FourDigitsAccont = string.Empty, regimentTax = string.Empty, 
                companyPhysicalAddress = string.Empty;

            DataTable dt = null;
            dsCorporatives.CCARD_corporatives_spSelectDataTable corporativesDt = null;
            dsCorporatives.dtResultsDataTable dtResults = null;
            //dsCorporatives.dtFiltersDataTable dtFilters = null;
            dsCorporatives.GAS_invoiceConsumptions_spListByIdClientProductPemexDataTable invoiceDt = null;

            try
            {
                string str = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logo_path"].ToString();
                string str2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rfc_path"].ToString();

                base.Server.MapPath("../images");
                string path = Server.MapPath("../" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pathReports"].ToString());

                Client cliente = new Client(pi_idClient);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cliente.bankReference))
                {
                    banckReference = cliente.bankReference;
                }

                dt = Invoices.listTableInvoiceConsuptionsByClient(pi_idClient, pi_idInvoice);

                CCARD_corporatives_spSelectTableAdapter corporativesTA = new CCARD_corporatives_spSelectTableAdapter();
                GAS_invoiceConsumptions_spListByIdClientProductPemexTableAdapter invoiceTA = new GAS_invoiceConsumptions_spListByIdClientProductPemexTableAdapter();
                GAS_invoiceConsumptions_spListByIdClient1TableAdapter resultsTA = new GAS_invoiceConsumptions_spListByIdClient1TableAdapter();

                invoiceDt = new dsCorporatives.GAS_invoiceConsumptions_spListByIdClientProductPemexDataTable();
                invoiceTA.Fill(invoiceDt, pi_idClient, pi_idInvoice);

                DataSet1.GAS_invoiceConsumptions_spListByIdClient1DataTable results = new DataSet1.GAS_invoiceConsumptions_spListByIdClient1DataTable();
                resultsTA.Fill(results, pi_idClient, pi_idInvoice);
                double totalInvoice = double.Parse(results.Compute("Sum(total)", "").ToString());
                //Cambio c1 = new Cambio();
                string sAmountText = NumberToText.doubleToText(double.Parse(results.Compute("Sum(total)", "").ToString())); //c1.EnLetras(double.Parse(results.Compute("Sum(total)", "").ToString())).Trim();

                for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
                {
                    results[i].amountText = sAmountText.ToUpper();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
                {
                    results[i].amountText = sAmountText.ToUpper();
                }

                Invoices invoice = new Invoices(pi_idInvoice);

                if (invoice.series != "TIJ" && invoice.series != "MXL" && invoice.number != invoice.idInvoice)
                {
                    isCFD = true;
                    series = invoice.series;
                    number = invoice.number.ToString("000000");
                }

                else
                {
                    isCFD = false;
                }

                if (invoiceDt.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    Client client = new Client(pi_idClient);
                    dsCorporatives.GAS_invoiceConsumptions_spListByIdClientProductPemexRow row = invoiceDt.NewGAS_invoiceConsumptions_spListByIdClientProductPemexRow();
                    row.CommissionsAmount = (decimal)0.0;
                    row.CommissionsTaxAmount = (decimal)0.0;
                    row.CommissionsValue = (decimal)0.0;
                    row.contact = string.Empty;
                    row.createdDate = invoice.createdDate.Date;
                    row.dateCreated = invoice.createdDate.Date;
                    row.description = string.Empty;
                    row.folio = string.Empty;
                    row.idCard = -1;
                    row.idClient = pi_idClient;
                    row.idConsumption = -1;
                    row.idInvoice = pi_idInvoice;
                    row.idPemex = string.Empty;
                    row.idStation = -1;
                    row.invoiceCreatedDate = invoice.createdDate;
                    row.operation = string.Empty;
                    row.operationType = string.Empty;
                    row.pemexKey = string.Empty;
                    row.price = (decimal)0.0;
                    row.printedDate = invoice.printedDate;
                    row.printNotes = invoice.printNote;
                    row.quantity = 0;
                    row.rfc = client.RFC;
                    row.stationName = string.Empty;
                    row.stationSaleNumber = 0;
                    row.subtotal = 0;
                    row.tax = 0;
                    row.TaxAmount = 0;
                    row.saleNumber = 0;
                    row.total = 0;
                    invoiceDt.AddGAS_invoiceConsumptions_spListByIdClientProductPemexRow(row);
                }

                corporativesDt = new dsCorporatives.CCARD_corporatives_spSelectDataTable();
                corporativesTA.Fill(corporativesDt, cliente.idCorporative);

                Zone companyBillingZone = new Zone(corporativesDt[0].idBillingZone);
                City companyBillingCity = new City(companyBillingZone.idCity);
                State companyBillingState = new State(companyBillingCity.idState);

                string companyBillingAddress = corporativesDt[0].billingStreet + " "
                                + " #" + corporativesDt[0].billingExtNumber
                                + (corporativesDt[0].billingIntNumber.Trim().Length > 0 ? "-" 
                                + corporativesDt[0].billingIntNumber : "")
                                + Environment.NewLine
                                + corporativesDt[0].billingNeighborhood
                                + Environment.NewLine
                                + companyBillingZone.description
                                + ", " + companyBillingState.description
                                + " C.P. " + corporativesDt[0].billingPostalCode;

                Zone companyPhysicalZone = new Zone(corporativesDt[0].idPhysicalZone);
                City companyPhysicalCity = new City(companyPhysicalZone.idCity);
                State companyPhysicalState = new State(companyPhysicalCity.idState);
                //los datos se deben tomar del xml
                /*string companyPhysicalAddress = corporativesDt[0].physicalStreet + " "
                                + " #" + corporativesDt[0].physicalExtNumber
                                + (corporativesDt[0].physicalIntNumber.Trim().Length > 0 ? "-" + corporativesDt[0].physicalIntNumber : "")
                                + Environment.NewLine
                                + corporativesDt[0].physicalNeighborhood
                                + Environment.NewLine
                                + companyPhysicalZone.description
                                + ", " + companyPhysicalState.description
                                + " C.P. " + corporativesDt[0].physicalPostalCode;*/

                dtResults = new dsCorporatives.dtResultsDataTable();
                dsCorporatives.dtResultsRow dRow = dtResults.NewdtResultsRow();

                double dblSubTotal = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Compute("Sum(subtotal)", "").ToString());
                double dblCommissionAmount = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Compute("Sum(CommissionsAmount)", "").ToString());
                double dblSubTotalWithOutidPemex = 0;
                double.TryParse(dt.Compute("Sum(subtotal)", "idPemex is null").ToString(), out dblSubTotalWithOutidPemex);
                double dblCommissionsTaxAmount = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Compute("sum(CommissionsTaxAmount )", "").ToString());
                double dblTotal = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Compute("sum(total)", "").ToString());
                double dblTaxAmountWithOutidPemex = 0;
                double.TryParse(dt.Compute("Sum(TaxAmount)", "idPemex is null").ToString(), out dblTaxAmountWithOutidPemex);
                double dblTotalWithOutidPemex = 0;
                double.TryParse(dt.Compute("Sum(Total)", "idPemex is null").ToString(), out dblTotalWithOutidPemex);
                double dblTaxAmount = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Compute("sum(TaxAmount)", "").ToString());
                double dblSubTotalOnlyProductsIdPemex = 0;
                double.TryParse(dt.Compute("Sum(subtotal)", "idPemex is not null").ToString(), out dblSubTotalOnlyProductsIdPemex);

                dRow.SubTotalReport = dblSubTotal + dblCommissionAmount;
                dRow.CommissionsAmount = dblCommissionAmount;
                dRow.SubTotalWithoutIdPemex = dblSubTotalWithOutidPemex;
                dRow.totalReport = dblCommissionsTaxAmount + dblCommissionAmount + dblTotal;
                dRow.totalCommissionAmount = dblCommissionAmount;
                dRow.totalCommissionTaxAmount = dblCommissionsTaxAmount;
                dRow.totalCommission = dblCommissionAmount + dblCommissionsTaxAmount;
                dRow.taxAmountwithoutIdPemex = dblTaxAmountWithOutidPemex;
                dRow.totalWithOutIdPemex = dblTotalWithOutidPemex;
                dRow.taxAmountReport = dblTaxAmount + dblCommissionsTaxAmount;
                dRow.SubTotalOnlyProductsIdPemex = dblSubTotalOnlyProductsIdPemex;
                dRow.CorporativeImage = this.GetImageData(string.Concat(new object[] { str, corporativesDt.Rows[0]["idCorporative"], "/", corporativesDt.Rows[0]["logo"] }));
                dRow.FiscalImage = this.GetImageData(string.Concat(new object[] { str2, corporativesDt.Rows[0]["idCorporative"], "/", corporativesDt.Rows[0]["imgRFC"] }));

                dtResults.AdddtResultsRow(dRow);

                if (isCFD)
                {
                    path = path + "crStatementOfAccountCFD.rpt";
                    oRpt.Load(path);
                }

                else
                {
                    path = path + "crStatementOfAccount.rpt";
                    oRpt.Load(path);
                }

                ReportDocument oSubRpt1 = oRpt.OpenSubreport("crSubResults");
                oSubRpt1.SetDataSource((DataTable)results);

                oRpt.Database.Tables["CCARD_corporatives_spSelect"].SetDataSource((DataTable)corporativesDt);
                oRpt.Database.Tables["GAS_invoiceConsumptions_spListByIdClientProductPemex"].SetDataSource((DataTable)invoiceDt);
                oRpt.Database.Tables["dtResults"].SetDataSource((DataTable)dtResults);

                ExportOptions exportOpts = new ExportOptions();
                PdfRtfWordFormatOptions pdfopts = ExportOptions.CreatePdfRtfWordFormatOptions();

                exportOpts.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                exportOpts.ExportFormatOptions = pdfopts;

                if (isCFD)
                {
                    //ElectronicInvoices.getInvoiceData(cliente.idCorporative, invoice.series, invoice.number, invoiceDt[0].invoiceCreatedDate, out originalString, out signedString, out approvedYear, out approvedNumber, out certificateNum);
                    ElectronicInvoices.getInvoiceData(cliente.idCorporative, invoice.series, invoice.number, invoiceDt[0].invoiceCreatedDate, out originalString, out signedString, out approvedYear, out approvedNumber, out certificateNum, out clientName, out clientDir, out clientRFC, out payMethod, out FourDigitsAccont, out regimentTax, out companyPhysicalAddress);

                    int lineLength = 204;
                    int j = originalString.Length / lineLength;

                    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
                    {
                        originalString = originalString.Substring(0, (i + 1) * lineLength + i * 2) + Environment.NewLine + originalString.Substring((i + 1) * lineLength + i * 2);
                    }

                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("series", series);
                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("number", number);

                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("clientName", clientName);
                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("clientDir", clientDir);
                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("clientRfc", clientRFC);

                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("originalString", originalString);
                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("signedString", signedString);

                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("approvedYear", approvedYear);
                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("approvedNumber", approvedNumber);
                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("certificateNumber", certificateNum);

                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("companyBillingAddress", companyBillingAddress);
                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("companyPhysicalAddress", companyPhysicalAddress);
                    //BanckReference
                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("banckReference", banckReference);
                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("payMethod", payMethod);
                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("4DigitsAccount", FourDigitsAccont);
                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("regimentTax", regimentTax);
                }

                else
                {
                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("series", invoice.series);

                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("clientName", cliente.tradeName);
                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("clientDir", cliente.fiscalAddress + " " + new Zone(cliente.idZone).description + ", " + new State(new City(new Zone(cliente.idZone).idCity).idState).description);
                    oRpt.SetParameterValue("clientRfc", cliente.RFC);
                }
                //Response.Clear();

                int iAdditionalRows = 0;

                if (results.Count > 2)
                {
                    iAdditionalRows = (results.Count - 2);
                }

                if (invoiceDt[0].printNotes.Length > 45)
                {
                    if (Math.Ceiling((decimal)(invoiceDt[0].printNotes.Length - 45) / 40) > iAdditionalRows)
                    {
                        iAdditionalRows = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)(invoiceDt[0].printNotes.Length - 45) / 40);
                    }
                }

                //Se ncesita mover txtContacto para que se "alinea" al bottom
                oRpt.ReportDefinition.Sections[7].ReportObjects["txtComentarios"].Height += iAdditionalRows * 340;
                oRpt.ReportDefinition.Sections[7].ReportObjects["txtContacto"].Top += iAdditionalRows * 340;
                oRpt.ReportDefinition.Sections[7].ReportObjects["txtContacto1"].Top += iAdditionalRows * 340;

                oRpt.ExportToHttpResponse(exportOpts, Response, false, "Exported");
            }

            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    oRpt.Dispose();
                    oRpt.Close();

                    corporativesDt.Dispose();
                    dtResults.Dispose();
                    //dtFilters.Dispose();
                    dt.Dispose();
                    invoiceDt.Dispose();
                }

                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }

        private byte[] GetImageData(string pi_fileName)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            System.Drawing.Image imageToConvert = new Bitmap(client.OpenRead(pi_fileName));
            return ConvertImageToByteArray(imageToConvert);
        }

        private static byte[] ConvertImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageToConvert)
        {
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            converter.ConvertTo(imageToConvert, typeof(byte[]));
            return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(imageToConvert, typeof(byte[]));
        }
```

MAIN PAGE

ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" CodeFile="PendingInvoices.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="Arkus.EnerCard.EnerCardWeb.portlets.PendingInvoices" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>
            PendingInvoices
        </title>

        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" />
        <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="C#" />
        <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript" />
        <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" />
        <link href="../css/Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script>
            function viewAll()
            {
                window.parent.location.href = "../reports/PendingInvoicesReport.aspx";
            }

            function onlinePayment()
            {
                window.parent.location.href = "../multipagos/onlinePayment.aspx";
            }

            function AddCredit(url)
            {
                window.parent.location.href = url;
            }

            function openLink (id,CouponInvoice)
            {
                document.getElementById('hdn').value = id;      
                __doPostBack('btnSaveSession','');
                window.open('../ClubCard/reportStatementOfAccount.aspx','Reporte');
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body id="bodyWhite">
        <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
            <input type="button" id="btnSaveSession" runat="server" value="saveSession" style="display:none" onserverclick="btnSaveSession_ServerClick" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hdn" runat="server" />

            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%">
                        <asp:DataGrid ID="dgInvoices" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"
                            DataKeyField="InvoiceId" PageSize="5" PagerStyle-CssClass="subT" AllowPaging="True"
                            PagerStyle-Visible="False">
                            <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="txtA" />
                            <ItemStyle CssClass="txtB" />
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="subT" />

                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="CouponInvoice" visible="false">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CouponInvoice") %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>

                                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Fecha">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# DateTime.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.date").ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yy") %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>

                                <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderText="Monto">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# double.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Charge").ToString()).ToString("C")%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>

                                <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderText="Saldo">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# (double.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Payment").ToString())).ToString("C")%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>

                                <asp:TemplateColumn>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <img id="imgPDF" src="../images/icons/pdf.gif" onclick='javascript:openLink(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.InvoiceId")%>,<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CouponInvoice") %> )' style="cursor: pointer" alt="" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:DataGrid>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="subT" width="100%" />
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

CS

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Arkus.EnerCard.Core;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Arkus.EnerCard.EnerCardWeb.portlets
{
    public partial class PendingInvoices : PageBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadDataGrid();
            }
        }

        override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {    
            this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Page_Load);

        }

        private void LoadDataGrid()
        {
            ClubCard.Core.Client _Client = CurrentClient;
            dgInvoices.DataSource = PendingInvoice.GetList(_Client.id, DateTime.Today.AddYears(-200), DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(1));
            dgInvoices.DataBind();

            if (ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["multipagosActive"] == "1" || ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["multipagosTestIdClient"] == _Client.id.ToString())
            {
                btnPagoLinea.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        protected void btnSaveSession_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["idInvoice"] = hdn.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see what you have made so far? It might just be a tiny bug in your system... no need to start over from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

With Crystal in ASP.Net, I load reports in the Page_Init not the Page_Load event. Also, the closing and disposing cleanup is handled in the Page_Unload event.

I noticed that the first report after the web application starts takes a considerable amount of time to load This is the Crystal runtime. After the first load, everything is fine. This will also happen after IIS shuts down the web application after idle time.

The only thing you can do about that is to warm up the crystal runtime. One option is to do this in your application at start up. Even it means calling a dummy blank crystal report at Application_Start from your global.asax.